# Swift iOS search bar loads custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am designing an iOS app with swift which looks like in the picture.

When the user taps on the search bar (first image), a new view should appear (second image) while the search bar stays focused. When the user puts in some search query the expanded view shall be updated. When the user selects a result, the expanded view should go away and show the table view with updated results (third image).

How can I model this custom search bar behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this scheme is to create 2 view..let's say for example A and B.

In view A there is a searchBar and your tableview with different cell. When searchBar got focused or is clicked view B is presented. When a cell is selected, view A is presented back calling maybe API for new data

Comment: This sounds logical. Is it possible to create kind of a modal (like modals from Twitter Bootstrap), which shows all the query result proposals (image 2)? If this is not a good practice, let me know. I am new to iOS development and Swift, therefore I hardly know best practices.